# SQL Server joins and where statements not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL Server statement, and I am not sure why it is returning no records:

```
SELECT 
    contacts.firstname , 
    contacts.lastname , 
    contacts.address1 , 
    contacts.city, 
    contacts.zip, 
    countries.title AS countrytitle, 
    states.title AS statetitle 
FROM providers, payableinvoices, contacts 
LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.countryid=contacts.countryid 
LEFT JOIN states ON states.stateid=contacts.stateid 
WHERE payableinvoices.payableinvoiceid=4 
AND providers.providerid=payableinvoices.providerid 
AND providers.contactid=contacts.contactid"
```

Simply, I have the following tables:

- contacts table: its columns include contactid, firstname, lastname, address1, city, zip
- providers table: its columns include providerid, contactid
- payableinvoices table: its columns include payableinvoiceid, providerid

So it is simply linking the primary keys and foreign keys together to get the require fields that correspond to that "payableinvoiceid", which has a provider assigned to it.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see an explicit join on `Providers`

Comment: Why has this question been made community wiki?

Comment: @Barry: the original question was very poorly formatted, so a lot of people went ahead and edited it. quite by coincidence, five people edited it within one minute, not knowing about the other edits. by design, after X of edits, the question is automatically CW'd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is standardise to use joins throughout:

```
SELECT 
    contacts.firstname , 
    contacts.lastname , 
    contacts.address1 , 
    contacts.city, 
    contacts.zip, 
    countries.title AS countrytitle, 
    states.title AS statetitle 
FROM providers
    INNER JOIN payableinvoices ON providers.providerid=payableinvoices.providerid 
    INNER JOIN contacts ON providers.contactid=contacts.contactid
    LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.countryid=contacts.countryid 
    LEFT JOIN states ON states.stateid=contacts.stateid 
WHERE payableinvoices.payableinvoiceid=4
```

The above looks fine to me.

If you're not getting the rows you expect back, you need to work your way up from the basic "SELECT...FROM providers" e.g.:

- start with a basic "SELECT....FROM providers"
- add the INNER JOIN to payableinvoices...test that
- add the WHERE condition...test that
  etc etc

So you'll soon find where the rows are being ruled out.

Comment: I found that my old code is working. It was just that that specific row of value "4" didn't have a "providerid" associated with it! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
SELECT 
    C.FirstName , 
    C.LastName , 
    C.Address1 , 
    C.City, 
    C.Zip, 
    CO.Title AS CountryTitle, 
    S.Title AS StateTitle 
FROM Contacts C
INNER JOIN Providers P ON P.ContactID = C.ContactID
INNER JOIN PayableInvoices PI ON PI.ContactID = P.ContactID
LEFT JOIN Countries CO ON CO.CountryID = C.CountryID 
LEFT JOIN States S ON S.StateID = C.StateID
WHERE PI.PayableInvoiceID = 4
```

Comment: Thanks, this showed an error because of this:
INNER JOIN PayableInvoices PI ON PI.ContactID = P.ContactID

it should be

INNER JOIN PayableInvoices PI ON PI.ProviderID = P.ProviderID


However, I found that my original code was working, just a missing value of "providerid" for that row of id "4".